# Install MSI at remote server or other machine

Tags: powershell

I am unable to install `.msi` files on any other computer or remote server. Is there any access type that should be given there?

I am trying to copy then invoke command to run MSI file on the target system, but my path is not recognized.

Copy folder from one to another setup:

```
Copy-Item "E:\tfs-13\Auto Upgrader Service\Dev\AutoUpgraderService" "E:\TRIAL\"  -Recurse
```

Run Setup at server:

```
msiexec.exe /qb /I "E:\TRIAL\AutoUpgraderService\Setup\bin\Debug\AutoUpgraderService.msi" INSTALLLOCATION=`"C:\Program Files`" ALT_DOC_DIR=`"C:\Program Files`"
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this...

```
psexec \\Server -u "DOMAIN\Username" -p "PASSWORD" cmd /c "msiexec.exe /i "\\Server\FolderShare\My Install.msi" /quiet /norestart"
```

Take a look at the hole explanation here:

http://forum.sysinternals.com/remote-install-of-msi-packages-using-psexec_topic22970.html

Answer (score 0):

if you copied and pasted your code from above, I noticed your quotes are wrong, you have

```
INSTALLLOCATION=`"C:\Program Files`" ALT_DOC_DIR=`"C:\Program Files`"
```

I believe it should be

```
INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files" ALT_DOC_DIR="C:\Program Files"
```